# How to call a variable of a function outside of a function?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, scope

I have used the following code to extend my short code and show inventory -

```php
if( !function_exists('so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode') ) {

    function so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode() {
        $product_ids_arr = [12, 944,993];
        $increment = 0;

        foreach ($product_ids_arr as $product_id) {

            $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();

            if($qty == 0) continue;

            if($increment == 1)return;

            $increment++;
                
            echo $esc = do_shortcode('[product_qty id="' . $product_id . '"]');
            
            global $next_value;
                
            $next_value = $esc+2;
        }
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'new_product_qty', 'so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode' );
```

However, I want to get value and show this variable's ($next_value) value outside of the `so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode` function. Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a `foreach` loop, I'm assuming you want to do something after each loop iteration, and not just the last one.

**Edit**

Based on the comments, I removed the previous hook and switched to a dedicated function that can be used in the shortcode or outside of it.

```php
function get_product_quantity_plus($product_id, $plus = 2) {
        echo $esc = do_shortcode('[product_qty id="' . $product_id . '"]');
        
        return $esc+2;
}

function so_extend_frequent_bought_shortcode() {
    $product_ids_arr = [12, 944,993];
    $increment = 0;

    foreach ($product_ids_arr as $product_id) {

        $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
        $qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        if($qty == 0) continue;

        if($increment == 1)return;

        $increment++;
            
        echo $esc = do_shortcode('[product_qty id="' . $product_id . '"]');
        
        global $next_value;

        $next_value = get_product_quantity_plus($product_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris Haas,
Thanks for your reply! The value of $esc is basically 7. The 5 is the inventory which is dynamically coming from woo commerce. I would like to show the "7" or the dynamic value through a short code in a place. Just checking your code too.
Thanks,

Comment: If you want to show a specific product inventory in a specific area, you don't need a global, you can just use `echo do_shortcode('[product_qty id="12"]');` in that specific area, substituting that ID as needed

Comment: Yes, I am getting the inventory value by call that short code or relevant function of woo commerce. But I want to add or plus 2 with current inventory and show that value in desired place. Ax example, if current inventory is 5, I want to show 7 and if current inventory is 7, I want to show 9.  Waiting to have your suggestion.

Comment: I've updated the code to remove my action, and instead I created a dedicated function that takes a `product_id` which I've used in the shortcode, but you can also use everywhere, would that work?

Comment: Thanks Chris Haas. The code worked for me!

Comment: @MdmaniruzzamanMoon, there should be a button where you can mark this as the accepted answer then.